# How much self induction would each coil of a transformer of one to one ratio be if the kVA rating for that transformer is 160?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

Assuming a current load of 80 A, and a voltage load of 1600 V, the straightforward kVA rating would be 128. But adjustments are made for power factor correction and other considerations raising the actual purchase of which transformer to take care of the situation to 160 kVA designation. My question is concerning one feature of 160 kVA transformer, namely: What would be the self induction on either of the two coils if they have the same self induction?

Comment: The self induction, presumably you mean inductance, is not defined by the kVA, or the rated load currents and voltages.

Comment: Depends. You have to compare the open circuit and short circuit behaviour of that transformer in question to calculate the respective inductivities.

Comment: For a big transformer it's going to be less than 1% of the total inductance of a winding when the other winding is unconnected. For small transformers it could be as much as 5%.